# How to create a Simple Class to move data around

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have some data which I need to move around between states and components {using Redux}, and I can't find a way to implement a simple class to package them all together to clean up my code ..

Ideally, I like to have:

```js
class Hero {
    constructor(name, level) {
        this.name = name;
        this.level = level;
    }
    get_name(this){
        return this.name
    }
    get_color(this){
        if (this.level>5){
            return "Blue"
         }
        return "Red"
    }
}
```

So I could have something like

```js
const people = [new Hero("A",10),new Hero("B",2)]
```

Anywhere in my react components...

It seems Reacts only allows me to import a "React Component" and when I did try this , It errors "react is not defined"

I am not using create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

That is not how redux function. Your are trying to implement the java behavior and it is not the same in redux.
In addition, with redux, we are not talking about "classes" but store.

I think you should look at the implementation of redux in react project. Here is a good one to start:
https://appdividend.com/2018/06/15/react-redux-axios-tutorial-example/